# Outook 2007 unable to configure with proxy server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, proxy-server

ERROR Msg ::
Log onto incoming mail server (IMAP): The host 'imap.gmail.com' cannot be found. Verify that the server name is typed correctly.

I would like to know format of combine the proxy authentication credentials with the IMAP server credentials **We are using IWSVA 5.0 as proxy server**

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your **proxy server** is not blocking Gmail **IMAP** ports or imap.gmail.com address? or has proper port mapping for below ports.
**Gmail** use these port for accessing via e-mail clients:

```
IMAP : 993
POP3 : 995
SMTP : 587 or 465
```